# PythonAnywhere `python3.6 -m venv test` Results in Error

Tags: pythonanywhere

I'm trying to use `python3.6 -m venv test` directly in PythonAnywhere to create a virtualenv. I wanted to use this method as I believe it is more portable to other environments where virtualenvwrapper might not be set up.

When I run the command (in a PA environment that has been upgraded to use Python 3.6) I get the following error.

```
12:34 ~ $ python3.6 -m venv test
Error: Command '['/home/dpottsagilisys/test/bin/python3.6', '-Im', 'ensurepip', 
'--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here: this appears to be a bug in Ubuntu 14.04 (and apparently 15.04), which we were based on when this question was originally asked.

[This Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1) has various suggestions; here's one that I've made 100% certain works on PythonAnywhere:

```
python3.6 -m venv --without-pip test
source test/bin/activate
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
deactivate
source test/bin/activate
```

[Update 28 June 2018: Switching to a 16.04 image is, coincidentally, what we're working on right now.]

[Update 30 September 2018: the 16.04 image is now live for new PythonAnywhere accounts]

Comment: Thanks! I got the same error on Fedora 26 and this workaround helped

Comment: "curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python" produced a 403 proxy error when I tried it.  Worked around it by pasting the get-pip.py into a file on github, then 'pull'ing the file down and running it.

Answer (score 12):

[Not having the package](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1059#issuecomment-313867040) `python3.6-venv` causes this issue. Installing with:
 `sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv` should resolve.

Comment: You save my day. Thank you.